# Mouse cursor scaling issues in Xubuntu 14.04 with XFCE 4.10

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, mouse, xfce

I am using Xubuntu 14.04 with XFCE 4.10 and I just recently bought a Seiki 39' 4K display for home. While I think that the display itself is working great so far and I love it, I am noticing some small quirks with the window manager or the desktop (I'm not sure exectly which).

One of these quirks is that the mouse cursor changes sizes depending on what it is hovering over on the screen. See below a few different examples on Thunderbird, Chrome and over the desktop.

[image: Thunderbird]

[image: Chrome]

[image: Desktop]

I didn't have this cursor scaling issue when I used a 1080p (1920x1080) screen and it started to happen when I connected the 4K screen. Is there a way for me to configure a uniform cursor size across all screens?

Comment: I have the exact same problem on Unity.

Comment: is there a fix?